How to resolve spacing issues with CarouselView inside a WebView and ScrollView in .NET MAUI?
(https://i.sstatic.net/mXYjWeDs.png)
I am building a .NET MAUI app that displays articles with the following functionalities:
Swipe right to left or left to right to move between articles.
Scroll up and down to view HTML content within each article.
Problem:
My articles have varying content lengths (bound from the ViewModel). When I swipe right to left to view the next article, I notice an issue particularly on the third item, which has longer HTML content. Scrolling to the bottom of this article shows extra unwanted space below the content.
Code Setup: I am using a ScrollView wrapped around a WebView to enable smooth vertical scrolling. However:
When I use the ScrollView, scrolling is smooth, but I encounter the extra space issue, especially with articles that have more text.
If I remove the ScrollView, the extra space disappears, but scrolling becomes less smooth, and the content occasionally swipes to the next article unintentionally when scrolling vertically (not ideal for user experience).
What I've Tried:
Wrapping and unwrapping the WebView in a ScrollView.
Adjusting the layout parameters, but I haven’t been able to eliminate the extra space without impacting scroll smoothness.
Question:
Is there a way to resolve this extra space issue while keeping the smooth scrolling experience? Any suggestions or alternative approaches to setting up CarouselView, WebView, and ScrollView for this use case would be greatly appreciated!
<ContentPage.Content>
    <CarouselView
        x:Name="carouselView"
        BackgroundColor="LightGreen"
        IsScrollAnimated="True">
        <CarouselView.ItemsSource>
            <Binding Path="CarouselItems" />
        </CarouselView.ItemsSource>
        <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ScrollView>
                    <WebView
                        x:Name="webView"
                        BackgroundColor="LightBlue"
                        Source="{Binding HtmlContent}" />
                </ScrollView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
    </CarouselView>
</ContentPage.Content>

 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
 {
     public MainPage()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
         BindingContext = new MainVM();
     }
 }

    public class MainVM
    {
        public ObservableCollection<CarouselItem> CarouselItems { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<CarouselItem>
    {
        new CarouselItem
        {
            Title = "Slide 1",
            HtmlContent = new HtmlWebViewSource
            {
                Html = @"
                    <div class='carousel-item'>
                        <h1>This is the content for Slide 1</h1>
                        <p>This is a sample content for slide 1.</p>
                    </div>"
            }
        },
        new CarouselItem
        {
            Title = "Slide 2",
            HtmlContent = new HtmlWebViewSource
            {
                Html = @"
                    <p data-id=""04c118d5-9a8a-45fc-86e9-980e1b2f465a"">In case anyone might have thought otherwise, the CQC has...</p>"
            }
        },
        new CarouselItem
        {
            Title = "Slide 3",
            HtmlContent = new HtmlWebViewSource
            {
                Html = @"
                    <p data-id=""3b241bef-b530-4649-b9f1-234681fca535"">Doctors working for an NHS body (or the HSC in Northern Ireland) will have access to NHS indemnity for claims for negligence through a clinical negligence scheme. But there are many circumstances where a doctor may need help and advice that are not included in NHS indemnity.</p> "
            }
        }
    };
    }

What I Tried and Expected Results:
To troubleshoot this issue, I created a .NET MAUI Proof of Concept (POC) app that replicates the space issue using a combination of CarouselView, WebView, and ScrollView. My project’s API returns article data in HTML format, which is bound to the view. For testing purposes, I hardcoded HTML content of varying lengths directly in the ViewModel to simulate real data.
What I’ve Tried:
Using ScrollView and WebView Together: I wrapped the WebView inside a ScrollView to enable smooth vertical scrolling. However, this setup leads to the unwanted extra space at the bottom of longer articles.
Adjusting Layout Properties: I experimented with properties like MinimumHeight on the ScrollView. With hot reload enabled, it appeared to work temporarily—displaying content correctly without the extra space. However, upon stopping and restarting the app, the extra space issue returned, indicating that these layout adjustments may only work partially or temporarily.
Expected Result:
I need a solution that prevents extra space from appearing at the bottom of the page, regardless of the length of the HTML content. Ideally, this setup should work consistently across app launches without relying on hot reload.
Testing Environment:
I tested this setup on both an Android device and an emulator, and both showed the same extra space issue.

WebView has its own Scroll you don't need to add one for it

You can try to set Visibility of Scrollview  false and true once navigated to new article (like refreshing the view). It may help invalidate the measure of the scrollview.

Change the  content of   DataTemplate   to 




 
, my codes worked fine.
I am unable to add bulk code here. Please add a lot of HTML data (more tags and content) in viewmodel; then only you will get space. Currently I am mentioned a few codes only.
Here:
Html = @"........."

Have you solved the problem ?

@liyu No, not yet solved

Here's the modified part of my code.My codes worked fine.
 <Frame> 
   <ScrollView> 
     <StackLayout> 
           <WebView x:Name="webView" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" Source=" 
            {Binding HtmlContent}"> 
           </WebView>
     </StackLayout>
  </ScrollView> 
</Frame>

